# "Integration by parts" for product of three functions with two derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I have the functional
$$L(f,g) = \int_0^1 f'(x) g'(x) h(x)\,dx.$$

Does there exist some function $H(x)$ such that
$$L(f,g) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 H(x,y) f(x) g(y)\,dxdy \quad + \quad \mathrm{boundary\ terms}? \tag{*}$$
And if so what is the formula for $H$?

In finite dimensions it is very easy to prove an identity of the form (*): $L$ is clearly bilinear, so I choose a basis and $H$ becomes a matrix whose entries are integrals of $h(x)$ times the derivatives of the basis functions.

But in infinite dimensions I am lost: I'm tempted to somehow apply integration by parts but I have no idea how to get something that looks like (*) (where would the second integral even come from)?